# Creating a toString for a Queue

Tags: java, queue, nodes, tostring

I am trying to create a toString method for a queue class that returns a string of the queue in the format of an array with the last value in the queue be the first in the string. For example if you added 1,2,3,4,5 to your queue in that order the toString method would return [5,4,3,2,1].

I've tried doing this but I can't seem to get the last value to print.

Here is the toString method I currently have

```
    public String toString( ) {
    if ( isEmpty() ) {
        return "[]";
    } else {

        String build = "";

        Node current = first;
        while ( current.getNext() != null ) {
            build = current.getElement() + ", " + build;
            current = current.getNext();
        }

        return "[" + build + "]";
    }
}
```

}

When I do my test as follows:

```
public class test {

public static void main( String[] args ){

    Queue q = new Queue(5);

    try {
        q.enqueue(1);
        q.enqueue(2);
        q.enqueue(3);
        q.enqueue(4);
        q.enqueue(5);

        System.out.println(q.toString());

    } catch (QueueFullException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

I keep getting:

```
[4, 3, 2, 1, ]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This approach will work:

```
@Override
public String toString ()
{
    String build = "";

    // I didn't want to make an assumption here - I don't know your implementation
    // If first is null when the queue is empty, then simplify this line
    Node current = (isEmpty()) ? null : first;

    while ( current != null )
    {
        String currElem = String.valueOf(current.getElement());

        // don't add the comma after the first element
        build = (build.length() == 0) ? currElem : currElem + ", " + build;

        current = current.getNext();
    }

    return "[" + build + "]";
}
```

**Note**: You don't need a special case for the empty queue - since the build string will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

please try to do the following

```
while ( current.getNext() != null ) {
             build = current.getElement() + ", " + build;
              current = current.getNext();
         } 
build = current.getElement() + build; // get the value of the last element
```

because in the last element there is not next, but you should to print the last value

Comment: This will have a comma after the last number.

Answer (score 0):

You are using current.getNext() check for traversing Queue elements. You can use

```
public String toString( ) {
if ( isEmpty() ) {
    return "[]";
} else {

    String build = "";

    Node current = first;
    while ( current != null ) {
        build = current.getElement() + ", " + build;
        current = current.getNext();
    }

    return "[" + build + "]";
}
```

This will resolve your problem. Thanks.